# How to order my resource by column count in SQL or scope?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models, `photos and albums`.

Photos `has many` albums.

Albums `has many` photos.

I have a join table called `Photo Listings`.

I want to order my photos by most albums to less, but I don't get it to work!

```
@most_albums_photos = @photos.joins(:photo_listings).order('COUNT(albums.id)')
```

I get the following error:

```
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "albums"
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "photos".id, COUNT(albums.id) AS alias_0 FR...
```

Any SQL man in the house? Thanks

#### Schema

```
  create_table "photo_listings", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "album_id"
    t.integer  "photo_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "albums", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.text     "description"
    t.integer  "cached_votes_total",      default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_score",      default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_up",         default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_down",       default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_weighted_score",   default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_weighted_total",   default: 0
    t.float    "cached_weighted_average", default: 0.0
    t.boolean  "selected",                default: false
  end

  create_table "photos", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "description"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "photo"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "category_id"
    t.integer  "zone_id"
    t.integer  "pins_count",            default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_total",    default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_score",    default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_up",       default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_votes_down",     default: 0
    t.integer  "cached_weighted_score", default: 0
    t.boolean  "terms"
    t.string   "slug"
    t.boolean  "sponsored"
    t.integer  "order"
    t.string   "url"
    t.boolean  "editor_pick",           default: false
    t.tsvector "tsv"
    t.boolean  "flash"
    t.boolean  "flash_active"
  end
```

Comment: The error is from `count(albums.id)`.. You didn't use this model `Album` but you are using it.. It should be ``count(albums_id)`..

Comment: Still wont work. What do you mean with the Album model? thanks for your time

Comment: What about `@photos.joins(photo_listings: :albums).order('COUNT(albums.id)')`?

Comment: The column name was album_id instead of albums_id, but now, I get the following: missing attribute: slug

Comment: @MrYoshiji hi, it gives me : Association named 'albums' was not found on PhotoListing; perhaps you misspelled it?

Comment: MrYoshji I think its because of the "s", since in PhotoListing model I have belongs_to :album. When removing the "s", I get this:PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "photos.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT  DISTINCT "photos".id, COUNT(albums.id) AS alias_0 FR...

Comment: add a simple `group('photos.id')` and it should work -- edit: Ah you figured it out yourself! Good job, have fun with Rails :)

Comment: Yep, that was it! Thanks MrYoshiji!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MrYoshji was almost there. Finally, I got it working with:

```
@most_albums_photos = @photos.joins(photo_listings: :album).group("photos.id").order('COUNT(albums.id) DESC')
```